# Appium Inspector not loading

Tags: ios, ipad, appium

Could not Launch Appium Inspector "Could not start a new session

Be sure the Appium server is running with an application opened by using the "App Path" parameter in Appium.app (along with package and activity for Android) or by connecting with selenium client and supplying this in the desired capabilities object."

```
   error: Failed to start an Appium session, err was: Error: Could not find a device to launch. You requested 'iPad 2 (7D3413F6-F99B-4B56-AF0D-5842278377B2) (8.1 Simulator)',
   but the available devices were: ["iPad 2 (8.1 Simulator) [7D3413F6-F99B-4B56-AF0D-5842278377B2]","iPad Air (8.1 Simulator) [AA6257B1-D3E0-49A6-85C2-F865B17ED6CD]","iPad Retina (8.1 Simulator) [6D0482A4-0951-43FF-AC0C-75C910B52FB7]","iPhone 4s (8.1 Simulator) [212DB040-8023-436D-936E-9ED2115715F3]",
  "iPhone 5 (8.1 Simulator) [7BD46F32-1080-4E35-9594-A3ED679FDED9]","iPhone 5s (8.1 Simulator) [536F6937-7CC7-42CD-984E-3B79FF163808]","iPhone 6 (8.1 Simulator) [C7F06CC8-934B-429A-9ED0-2637A069502A]","iPhone 6 Plus (8.1 Simulator) [19D4AA61-799E-4018-BB1D-B73FB51E7629]"]
```

Can anyone help me come out of this? I am very new to Appium

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

After 1 day of research i figured it out just remove the udid next to ur device while setting up and uncheck the udid and launch , first you may get inspector couldnot be launched nothing to worry just restart the appium and try it again your inspector will be launched

Comment: I can't get this to work.  I am launching the iOS sample UI Catalogue app and selecting "Prelaunch Application" from the settings panel.  After the app launches on the sim and I press the inspector button, I always get the error "Could not get list of sessions from Appium Server".

Answer (score 0):

You can try change the sever address be 127.0.0.1.For the first you can try
just launch one device.If still can't launch,you can try launch appium by commend: appium -U  --app  -p  .I'm so sorry for my poor English,if can give you some help I will be very happy.